# Where does gsutil copy my file to if the first backslash of the bucket path is missing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, gsutil, cp

I tried to copy a file from a GCP VM to my bucket using a command like this:

```
gsutil cp FILE.txt gs:/BUCKET_NAME/FOLDER/FILE.txt
```

Note that I should have two slashes after "gs:" instead of just one but I still got a message on my STDOUT saying the file was copied along the lines of:

> Copying file://FILE.txt...
>
> / [0 files][    0.0 B/ 62.8 MiB]
>
> / [1 files][ 62.8 MiB/ 62.8 MiB]
>
> Operation completed over 1 objects/62.8 MiB.

I realized my mistake when I checked that part of my bucket and saw the file wasn't there. My question is: where did I copy that file to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `:` character is a valid directory name on some operating systems, you end up creating a directory hierarchy within the directory you're running the command in.  The file gets copied to the path under `{current dir}` > `gs:` > `BUCKET_NAME` > `FOLDER`.  Look in your current directory for a directory named `gs:`.